# How to control webapp accessing between webview and web browser?

Tags: laravel-5, web-applications, webview

What I have

- A webapp with Laravel 5.6.
- A webview with React Native.

What I want to do

1. Only allow users to access to webapp via Webview.
2. Allow all users to access to home page of webapp via web browsers.
3. Allow web administrators to access to admin pages of webapp via both
   of webview and web browsers.

My questions

1. Can I control these golds only with Laravel?
2. If yes, how to do it?
3. Should I separate homepage of webapp and content page of webapp into
   2 difference domain (or sub domain)?
4. Or is therer any other suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is what i got after extracting android from react, we need to do following changes in android 
MainActivity.java

```
// REMOTE RESOURCE
mWebView.loadUrl("YOUR_URL_HERE");
```

And

MyWebViewClient.java : just return false

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
//        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("YOUR_URL_HERE")) {
//            return false;
//        }
//
//        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
//        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
//        return true;
        return (false);
    }
```

Hope it helps

Here's is my webview screenshot
[image: FRONT-END AND BACK-END IN WEBVIEW]